# elasticsearch: "How to retrieve the content of a mapping field"

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I did a python script which indexes a set of email into elasticsearch, defining a mapping. Now I should do another script in order to retrieve the content of the body of the email (which is a mapping field named `message_body`) and perform some preprocessing actions like tokenizing, removing stopwords and stemming. Finally I should index again the body of all the email once they got preprocessed.

How could I get just the body mapping field using elasticsearch dsl?

Comment: This should be achievable via the [`source`](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#extra-properties-and-parameters) method of the `search` object.

Comment: It works! Thank you

Comment: Ok now I'm facing some problems in removing stopwords in email bodies. I printed them on terminal stdout so How can I handle each word of each body?